# my file is outputing to screen twice c++?

Tags: c++, file, data-structures

hi guys i writing a code and my file is outputting some words twice? help

this are methods of class. i call the in main program. the create list is okay but display is the one with problem.

it is displaying some items twice and mostly items of last entry.

```
  void Books ::createList()
  {

  ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("bookshop.txt",ios::out );


   cout << "enter the size of list" << endl;
   cin >> n;

   if (n <= 0)
   {
    cout << "invalid entry or list empty" << endl;
   }///end if.
  else
   {
    i = 1 ;

    if (i > n)
        tmp1Ptr->next = NULL;

    else
        cout << "enter value for the list" << endl;
    for(i=1; i<=n ; i++)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "enter the author" << endl;
        getline(cin , authr);

        cout <<endl << "enter the title" << endl;
        getline(cin , titl);

        cout << endl << "enter the publisher" << endl;
        getline(cin , publishr);

        cout << endl<< "enter the price" << endl;
        cin >> pric;

        cout << endl << "enter the stock position" << endl;
        cin >> stoc;

        tmp2Ptr = new Book;
        tmp2Ptr->author = authr ;
        tmp2Ptr->title = titl ;
        tmp2Ptr->publisher = publishr ;
        tmp2Ptr->price = pric ;
        tmp2Ptr->stock = stoc ;
        outfile<<tmp2Ptr->author << endl;
        outfile<<tmp2Ptr->title <<endl;
        outfile<<tmp2Ptr->publisher <<endl;
        outfile<<tmp2Ptr->price <<endl;
        outfile<<tmp2Ptr->stock <<endl;

        if (i == 1)
        {

            headPtr = tmp2Ptr;
            tmp1Ptr = headPtr ;
            tmp1Ptr->prev = NULL;

        }///end inner if
        else
        {

            tmp1Ptr->next = tmp2Ptr;
            tmp2Ptr->prev = tmp1Ptr;
            tmp1Ptr = tmp2Ptr;


        }///end inner else.



    }///end for
    tmp1Ptr->next = NULL;
    tmp1Ptr = NULL;
    tmp2Ptr = NULL;

    cout << endl;

 }
 outfile.close();

 }///end createList

  void Books ::displayDetails()
   {
   ifstream infile;
   infile.open("bookshop.txt", ios::in);


  cout << "contents of list are:" << endl;

               while (infile.good())
               {
                string priz;
               string stok;



               getline(infile,authr1);
               getline(infile,titl1);
               getline(infile,publishr1);
               getline(infile,priz);
               getline(infile,stok);




               cout<< authr1 << endl;
                cout<< titl1 << endl;
                cout<< publishr1 << endl;

                cout << priz << endl << stok << endl;


               }





               infile.close();
                }
```

Comment: Before you ask for help, please reduce your code to the minimum and remove obsolete whitespace and so on. This encourages people to help you.

Comment: @joachin pile borg. the getline stuff worked and if i want to search from file the title and author how do i do it and dislay the full info about a certain title on screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do `while (infile.good())` (or `while (!infile.eof())` for that matter), as it will not work as expected (as you noticed). Instead do e.g. `while (getline(...))`.

The problem is that the `eofbit` flag will not be set until after you try to read from *beyond* the end of the file, as there is no reliable way to detect end of file until you actually have reached it and try to go beyond it. This causes a loop like `while (infile.good())` to iterate once to many, and then all the `getline` calls inside the loop will fail (with the first call setting the `eofbit` flag), but since you don't check for that inside the loop you will print out invalid data.

Instead rely on the fact that [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) return the stream object (or rather a reference to it) and that a stream can [be used in a boolean expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). So if the `getline` call fails, then the correct flags will be set in the stream when `getline` returns, and the stream will evaluate to `false` when used in the condition stopping the loop.

Comment: @joachin Pileborg. the getline stuff worked and if i want to search from file the title and author how do i do it and dislay the full info about a certain title on screen

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your loop:

```
*while (infile >> authr1 >> titl1 >> publishr1 >> priz >> stok)
  cout<< authr1  << titl1  << publishr1  << priz << stok << endl;*
```

The eof does not reach until you actually read eof so the while(infile.good()) wont work.